# Sample of Northwind in EF Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, northwind

Is there a sample of the complete Northwind database model out there built with EF Code First? I'm trying to understand the structure and  correctly reflect foreign key relationships. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did u try reverse engineering with the model first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope u have the database of Nothwind. Next follow the steps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using VS 2010, let me install the EF Power Tools and give it a shot.

Comment: Managed to generate a whole load of class files. Now I just need to translate the concept of multiple int fields as a string into my own model. Thanks for your help.